# Is it possible to activate & deactivate bump api within a single viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, api, uiviewcontroller, bump

I'm using the bump api which is available [here](https://github.com/bumptech/bump-api-ios). I have this completely setup in my app, but what I want to do is only have it activated within a single viewcontroller. I notice that regardless of the view you're in the bump is still activated.

I didn't install the code in the AppDelegate.m file, its in a ViewController.m file. After my last test, it obvious it doesn't matter where I put the code.

So I'm wondering if there is a way to turn it off(disconnect)? I would like to do this when a user switches views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `disconnect` and `connect` on your `BumpClient` whenever you feel it is appropriate... see [here](https://github.com/bumptech/bump-api-ios/blob/master/libBump/BumpClient.h).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I probably should have look at that file a little closer (signs that I'm still a novice iOS Developer). :D